# Symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 zbar

Tags: ios, xcode, zbar, i386

[image: compile error]

I can't run my application cause of this crazy error. Everything ran great before I updated from Xcode 6 to 7.

Comment: Hi Berk, Welcome to stackoverflow, Please post the segment of the code where you get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import AVFoundation and AudioToolbox frameworks and also set i386 armv6 armv7 armv7s architectures needed for running the libraries.

**OR**

The 7 frameworks need to be in the following order:

```
Foundation.framework
CoreGraphics.framework
UIKit.framework
AVFoundation.framework
CoreMedia.framework
CoreVideo.framework
QuartzCore.framework
libiconv.dylib
libzbar.a
```

I wasn't aware the order the frameworks are declared in the Build Phases mattered. Anyways, hopefully for anybody trying to integrate a barcode scanner into their app, this answer will be useful.

Comment: I already add all of them also architecture is correct.But still not running.I gues it is because of mac os version or xcode version.I have another mac which is not updated yet.On there i can run the project.Bu in os 10 or hihger with xcode it doesnt run.What should i do ? I am glad you to answer..

Comment: If you are using Xcode 7 then sometimes its gives error on build so just try to reinstall Xcode 7 again on your system.